# PHP/AJAX-based Overall Website Security

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, security

I wanted to get an opinion on how secure my current website is at the moment; I just realized that I had a hole in how I processed content for my site, so I want to make sure I don't have any other problems.

My site works as follows: there is only one actual "file" (the template for the page) that is requested.

Using AJAX, content is loaded into the body of the page each time a link is clicked (so the footer and header always stay in place).

The content for each of these pages are stored in JSON within a similar data structure as my website (i.e. example.com/about's content would be stored in example.com/json/about/data.json). I use JSON because not only is the html for the body of the page stored, but also some custom CSS (which will be injected into the header), the title of the page, and some other attributes are stored as well.

When getting the body content from the server, a connector script (example.com/getcontent.php) is used to retrieve the appropriate content for a page. This connector script is used because within the JSON body content, there is PHP code for pages that require it. The connector script evals the content and then sends the output to the browser.

The security hole I found was that anyone could just go to example.com/json/page/data.json and read all of the PHP code I wrote within the body for each page. I plan to fix this by using mcrypt to encrypt the JSON after creating it, and again using mcrypt within get.php to decrypt it.

Since this is such a big security vulnerability, in my opinion, I was wondering if anyone else could think of something similar that could be wrong with my setup.

**NOTE:** Only I have access to the server (thus, only I can create the JSON that is evaled), so content that shouldn't be evaled isn't a problem because I am the one that writes the content for each page.

Comment: I don't understand why you're sending PHP code to another file that eval()'s it, it seems such a design flaw in the overall website, not just security.

Comment: Voting to close this - it takes days/weeks even months to evaluate the security of a website properly. A few lines in a post here is not enough information for people to provide a free security analysis from. Given the obvious nature of the disclosed vulnerability, there is a high probability of other problems with the site.

Comment: Well, for each page, I basically have a JSON object that is as follows - {css, title, html, other}. Within HTML, I sometimes will have PHP code (such as getting a template for a sidebar, downloading info from another site using cURL, etc) that needs to be evaled. I can't really think of another way to execute that code without eval'ing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your JSON data outside the web root and make sure that your getcontent.php only serves data from exactly that directory.

So if your web root is /home/website/htdocs, store the json in /home/website/data for example.

In that getcontent.php, make sure that you strip out all .. from the input or use realpath like this:

```
define(APP_ROOT, '/home/website');
$p = realpath(APP_ROOT.'/data/'.$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
if (!preg_match('#^'.realpath(APP_ROOT).'#', $p)){
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die("Access denied");
}
```

then you can reference any file in that data folder by a URL in the form of getfile.php/path/to/the/json-file.json

Comment: This is a great idea! I didn't even think of storing the JSON files outside of the public HTML directory; keeping it out of there will prevent anyone from looking at the JSON directly.

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted my previous answer as I'd misunderstood what you were saying. (and the question really isn't very clear, so it's possible I'm still not getting it)

I *still* say that any usage of `eval()` on the server is a security risk. No matter how tightly you think you've controlled it, if your PHP code contains an `eval()` call, there is a very good chance that it's wide open to being hacked.

Don't take that risk: don't use `eval()` in PHP. **Ever**<sup>†</sup>.

In addition, using `eval()` means that PHP can't pre-compile the code, so it'll run much slower than normal PHP code.

You can get away with using `eval()` in client-side Javascript because (a) it's the only way to parse JSON in some browsers, and (b) the client can run any Javascript code he likes anyway using Firebug or similar tools. (It'll still be slow, though, so you should still avoid it where possible).

<sup>†</sup> [edit] To appease @symcbean, I should clarify that you should never use `eval()` *except* in the few occasions where it is the best solution to the problem at hand, and only once you have a firm understanding of the risks involved with using it. These situations are few and far between, however: I've seen `eval()` used a lot, but I've never come across code using it properly; it's always been bad code.

Comment: Is there some sort of alternative? Certain pages on my site need to use PHP to perform actions, such as downloading content from another website or including a template for a sidebar, etc. I know that eval is a great risk if exposed to the client, but the content being evaled can only come from the files stored within my server (the get.php file takes in a POST request like '/about' and gets the file /home/website/about/data.json from my server).

Comment: Why do you need to eval it? Why not have the PHP stored as PHP normal files, and have just the filename in the JSON. Then you can do `include_once($filename);` rather than using `eval()`. This still has security implications (you'd need to validate the filename, etc), but much better than `eval()`.

Comment: But the filename is already being validated, as the POST request accepted by get.php takes in a path that must be relative to /home/website/json or something similar. Why have two files (data.json containing information about the page, and data.php containing the html/PHP for the page) when that data.php would essentially be "evaled" anyway by including it?

Comment: Consider the possibility of a buffer-overflow bug allowing a hacker to overwrite a variable in your program with an arbitrary value (this has been known to happen). If your variable contains PHP code, and the hacker can overwrite it, then he can do a lot more damage than if it's a filename. There are other ways he could hack it too; overwrite the JSON file, for example. Finally, if you `include()` it, then it won't be eval()ed, but run as part of the main PHP program, which will give you *much* better performance.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of a bug like that being able to happen. Also, I like to optimize things as much as I can, so if performance is much better with including the file then perhaps I'll do just that. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The way eval() was being used by skoshy was wrong. But there are potential abuses for **EVERY** bit of functionality in PHP (e.g. print $_GET['a']; - should we ban print?). There are a lot of very valid, secure uses for eval() which canot be sensibly implemented by other means. eval is not evil

Comment: @symcbean -- technically you're right of course; if it didn't have valid uses, it wouldn't be in the language (and in loads of other languages too). **BUT** the point is that it is generally used in the wrong way, and unless one has a good understanding of how to use it correctly, the best advice is not to use it at all. I'll edit my answer if you like to clarify that, but I don't feel I was wrong to advise him never to use eval -- I would advise anyone the same who asked, unless they demonstrated an understanding of the risk, and were in a situation where eval was the only solution.